# Writing script in windows to run two command line in ConEmu

Tags: conemu

I was wondering if I can write some kind of script for ConEmu so that I can start two command lines with some parameter. Here what I am trying to do:

```
$ start app1 someParam //start in one cmd line tab
$ start app2 otherParam //start in second cmd line tab
```

Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direction? Docs of course. [LaunchNewTab](http://conemu.github.io/en/LaunchNewTab.html), [CommandLine](http://conemu.github.io/en/CommandLine.html), [-new_console](http://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html), [Tasks](http://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html). Numerous methods for any case.

Actually, you question is not clear. What do you want to run and where? The [docs](http://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html#Example4) show several examples how to run several tabs at once. For example:

```
ConEmu -cmdlist app1 someParam ||| app2 otherParam
```